# Drawing polar graphs when given theta in terms of the radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I know how to plot when it is like

> $r=10 \cdot \sin(2\theta)$.

But how to do that when the condition is like:

> $\theta =2 \pi \cdot \sin(r)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to imagine the polar coordinate grid.  Each of the circles represents a different value of $r$, and each of the lines represents a value of $\theta$.

[image: polar grid]

What you do is you pick a few values of the radius, say $r = 1$, $r=2$, $r=3$, $r=4$, and $r = 5$.  For each one, compute what $\theta$ is.  Then draw the point $(r, \theta)$ for each.  To find the point, just locate the circle for $r$, and then go around the circle to find the angle $\theta$.

Comment: you mean θ=2π⋅sin(1), θ=2π⋅sin(2), θ=2π⋅sin(3) and so on? but does it make sense?

Comment: @user2965303 Yes, that is what I mean.  In this case you have sort of a weird function, so it might make sense to pick nicer things for $r$, like $\pi$, $\pi/2$, $\pi/3$, and so on.

Comment: but could you explain me what shoul I do next, I didn't understand correctly what you said in your post

Comment: @user2965303 You have computed $\theta = 2 \pi \sin(1)$.  Now that means $r$ is $1$ and $\theta$ is $2 \pi \sin(1)$.  Since $r$ is $1$, the point you need to plot is on the first circle, i.e. the circle with radius $1$.  Then you go around that circle until you get the point with angle $2 \pi \sin(1)$, which should be about .84 of a full turn around the circle.

Comment: you mean that f.e. if i pick r=π , then i need to locate (π;0), then if i pick π/2 I need to locate (π/2;2π) to that graph?

Comment: @user2965303 Yes.

Comment: but it is hard to know how many R's I will need and the distance between them?

Comment: @user2965303 $r$ is the distance to the origin.  Each of the circles represents distance $1$, distance $2$, and so on.  $\pi$ is $3.14$, which means the distance to the origin should be just a bit outside the $3$rd circle.

Comment: lets say i pointed (π;0) and (π/2;2π)  what i can do next?

Comment: @user2965303 Find the imaginary circle that is about $\pi$ from the origin, and then find the point angle $0$ around that circle.  Do the same for $r = \pi / 4$, $r = \pi/2$, $r = 3 \pi / 4$.

Comment: now i have 4 dots on coordinate grid, I dont get what to do with them

Comment: @user2965303 Connect them.  They form the graph. But you will probably have to draw more points before you see how they connect.

Comment: @user2965303 The final plot is going to look like this. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r+%3D+arcsin%28theta+%2F+%282+pi%29%29+polar

Comment: now i got it, thanks. By the way how do you get that arcsin(theta / (2 pi)) from?

Comment: @user2965303 I solved for r in your equation $\theta = 2 \pi \sin(r)$. :)

Comment: mm one more question how to turn 2π*sin(3π/4) in to the angle?

Comment: @user2965303 $2 \pi$ is a full turn around the circle.  Then since $\sin(3 \pi / 4) = -\sqrt{2}/2$ , you have to go $-\sqrt{2}/2 \approx -71 \%$ of a turn counterclockwise, or $71\%$ of a turn clockwise.

Comment: how to decide direction?

Comment: @user2965303 Postive: counterclockwise.  Negative: clockwise.

Comment: how about if there would be π⋅sin(r) instead of 2π⋅sin(r) ?

Comment: @user2965303 Write it as $2\pi \cdot \frac12 \sin(r)$.  But if you have a new question, well, ask a new question.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion in the comments.  You can use chat for this type of conversation.